# Cassandra Upsert not working on conditional writes

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cql

I made an conditional insert(if not exists) statement using `datastax` java driver. Now when I try to update the same record immediately using `cassandra` update or insert statements, its not getting updated from `datastax` java driver.

After 5-10 min the same record is getting updated using same java program. Why is this lag or this is some `cassandra` feature which I am not able to understand. Because `cqlsh` is working fine.

`Cassandra version 2.2.8` and `driver version 3.2.0`

Comment: A 5-10 min lag is pretty hard to think of a cause for. Can you provide some CQL or code to further explain what your doing?

Comment: 1) first step i am inserting using conditional insert statement " insert into table () values () if not exists"
2) second step i am trying to  updae the same record using normal "update statment update table set columnName = value where columnName= value"